# slidedown next element

Tags: jquery

I've created a list from table records and i added a rightclick event for showing a menu. When you click on edit user there must slide down a form for editing the user.

I've made an example of my list:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Ku7h/6/

The problem is to slide down the right form, I only get it working for the first and the last form. I tried it with next() but that didn't work.

I hope someone can help me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#editUser').click(function(e) {
    $('.table_record_selected').next().next().slideDown(500);
});
```